# HTML table text in rows alignment

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML table which have text and numbers with different font size.

As you see big number are not aligned with the row text. How I can align them via CSS?

My CSS code:

```
.data_table_pricing {
    border-spacing: 12px;
    border-collapse: separate;
    width: 600px;
}
```

[image: HTML table alignment]

Comment: Put your actually css pls

Comment: done. I'm using JSF as back end.

Comment: what's the html? make a fiddle it would really help